# Interface Builder crash with assert in IBPlatformToolFailureHandler.m

Tags: interface-builder, xcode7, assert, uistackview

[image]I'm using Xcode 7.0.1 and since several days I'm experiencing very frequent crash with the Interface Builder when setting properties of UIStackViews.

I have reproduced the issue with a very simple project created from scratch. This project just contains a Storyboard with a Single viewController that contains a UITableView with a UITableViewCell which contains 5 UILabels with several UIStackViews.

Every time I'm changing several properties of one of the UIStackView Xcode crash, with error below.

Sometime I can reopen the project and sometimes not (Xcode crash at startup). I have the same issue with the same project on my MacBookPro and my old white MacBook, all are running with the same version of Xcode and OS X El Capitain.

Any idea about a workaround or a way to fix it is welcomed.

Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               7.0.1 (8228)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-8228000000000000~5
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       813434267
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQCrM.png)
Responsible:           Xcode [2177]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-10-10 18:29:07.206 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A284)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        4CEF61B0-80F0-668D-225D-39382C5053E4

Sleep/Wake UUID:       C7D655B2-BA3E-4DAF-AC3A-F9AB2B1609DC

Time Awake Since Boot: 13000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       8800 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
IBDocumentDidFinishEditingNotification
ProductBuildVersion: 7A1001
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-8191/InterfaceBuilderKit/Utilities/IBPlatformToolFailureHandler.m:315
Details:  Failed to compute auto layout status IBLayoutConstraint, IBUILabel, IBUIStackView, IBUITableViewCell, IBUITableViewCellContentView, and IBUIView.

Encountered an error communicating with Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool. If you choose to file a crash report or Radar for this issue, please zip and attach the diagnostics at "/var/folders/q3/g2n6m_1x57583jym4b_808jw0000gn/T/IB-agent-diagnostics_2015-10-10_18-29-07_130000" to your crash report.

Exception name: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Exception reason: {objective 0x7ff0e2677310: <1:20> + <1:1>*0x7ff0e268c6c0.marker{id: 4430}}: internal error.  Setting empty vector for variable UILabel:0x7ff0e4c71c20'Last Period'.Height{id: 4185}.
Exception backtrace: 
  0. CoreFoundation           0x0000000109dfbf4d __exceptionPreprocess
  1. libobjc.A.dylib          0x0000000109875deb objc_exception_throw
  2. CoreFoundation           0x0000000109dfbe9d +[NSException raise:format:]
  3. Foundation               0x000000010944e930 -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression setPriorityVector:forKnownAbsentVariable:]
  4. Foundation               0x00000001095f01b7 __128-[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression replaceVariable:withExpression:processVariableNewToReceiver:processVariableDroppedFromReceiver:]_block_invoke
  5. Foundation               0x000000010944b47f -[NSISLinearExpression enumerateVariablesAndCoefficients:]
  6. Foundation               0x00000001095f0077 -[NSISObjectiveLinearExpression replaceVariable:withExpression:processVariableNewToReceiver:processVariableDroppedFromReceiver:]
  7. Foundation               0x000000010944c5ae -[NSISEngine substituteOutAllOccurencesOfBodyVar:withExpression:]
  8. Foundation               0x000000010944f5ed -[NSISEngine pivotToMakeBodyVar:newHeadOfRowWithHead:andDropRow:]
  9. Foundation               0x000000010944cf87 -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:]
 10. Foundation               0x00000001095ebe43 -[NSISEngine tryUsingArtificialVariableToAddConstraintWithMarker:rowBody:usingInfeasibilityHandlingBehavior:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
 11. Foundation               0x000000010944ae4e -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
 12. Foundation               0x00000001095f2a09 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
 13. Foundation               0x000000010943f96d -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
 14. UIKit                    0x0000000107b31590 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
 15. UIKit                    0x0000000107b31966 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraintWithoutUpdatingConstraintsArray:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
 16. UIKit                    0x0000000107b31adf -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _tryToAddConstraint:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
 17. IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation 0x00000001071e0ea0 -[IBCocoaTouchToolAutolayoutEngine tryToAddConstraint:toRepresentedView:roundingAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]

Comment: Show me the layout in storyboard and I can help you with a workaround

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks a lot!
I have added in the original post a screenshot with the layout in Interface Builder. The screenshot is with Xcode 7.1 beta 3, the same project with Xcode 7.0.1 crashes. At least Xcode 7.1 beta 3 detects an issue...
This layout is very simple and easy to reproduce. I have filled a bug but no feedback from Apple.

Comment: I am getting similar issue when setting UILabel.font via code, still no clue why.